# Problem when registering with StackOverflow careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, jobs

I have been invited to StackOverflow careers. However, when trying to register with the site I am getting the following error message:

> Hmm, that email already exists on
>   another account. You will need to log
>   out of your existing account and log
>   back in.

Anything you could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there, you had two accounts. I've merged them and you should be all set.

Comment: Could you do the same for me? I'm editing my profile to insert my email but I just can't and I had to create it with another profile. Thank you!

Comment: @oscar already done (replied to the email you sent)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I've seen some other issues but I guess I will create a new meta question or just contact you by the provided email.